# Bulk adding users to AzureAD Script error

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

The goal of the script is to run and add all users with a specific job title to an AzureAD Group.
I've tested the variable and it grab the right people and will display if I write the variable to the screen.

The error message I get states "ADD-AzureADGroupMember : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter.

```
#Grab all users with the job title IT Support Technician
$User = (Get-AzureADUser -All $true | 
Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.JobTitle -eq "IT Support Technician"}).ObjectId

#Grab the ObjectID of the AzureADGroup
$Branch = (Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "Test SG").ObjectId

#Add each of the Users to the AzureADGroup
$User | ForEach-Object {
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $Branch -RefObjectId $User
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating over `$user` then trying to add all users within your `Foreach-Object` loop.

To reference the current pipeline item you can use `$_` or `$PSItem`

```
$User | ForEach-Object {
    Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $Branch -RefObjectId $_
}
```

#### Documentation on Automatic Variables

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#_

Comment: Thank you! That worked wonderfully and was a shockingly easy fix